# Jquery - sending data with $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax

### I am trying to store clicked link in database

```
<a id="downloads" href="http://example.com/filename?hello.rar">Download</a>



$('#downloads').click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
var url ="http://www.example.com/count.php?filename=hello.rar";
$.get(url, function(data) {});
});
```

Link gets stored in database but file download don't start **http://example.com/filename?hello.rar**
if i remove `event.preventDefault();`  download start but it don't save link in database

Please provide some solution to this or Suggest any better way to do this.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### #1

**Change CLICK listener to listen for a class or else you can only have one link**

### #2

**Do what you see below**

Something like this should work:

**HTML**

```
<a class="downloads" href="http://example.com/filename?hello1.rar" target="_blank">Download 1</a>
<a class="downloads" href="http://example.com/filename?hello2.rar" target="_blank">Download 2</a>
<a class="downloads" href="http://example.com/filename?hello3.rar" target="_blank">Download 3</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.downloads').click(function(){

    var clickedURL = $(this).attr('href');

    $.get('http://www.example.com/yourSaveURLToDatabaseScript', {'url': clickedURL});

});
```

Comment: See edit, open the download link in a new tab. Most browsers are set to close the tab if they detect a file download like this.

Comment: thanx a ton.i was search whole night for this.

Comment: just take note that, this is not a reliable way of tracking downloads,  you can just extract http logs from your web server for a more accurate statistics..

Comment: @Lee plz provide some code snippet or link to do so.

Comment: @YogeshLakhotia it depends on what web server you are using, a high level design would be to use regex to extract the statistics

Comment: @LeeGary You are right, this is not a reliable method. However, HTTP logs can get gigantic. If you are going to recommend extracting data from them then please explain how you plan to make sure this extraction never slows down due to the size of the log.

Comment: it all really depends on what web server and how the logs are written, saving to db using ajax is not the best way to go definitely, i'd rather use google analytics events to track those

Comment: @LeeGary Very well said and I do not disagree